# How to define a variable in apache's httpd.conf file?

Tags: apache

I want to define a variable in Apache server's `httpd.conf` configuration file.

Ex: variable static_path = `C:\codebase\snp_static`

and I want to use this variable (static_path) in `httpd.conf` where ever required.

Please tell me how can define a variable in `httpd.conf` file ?

Comment: check that response for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343621/conditions-in-apache/6346407#6346407

Comment: should / could this question be moved to serverfault? https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Also see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_macro.html - this can often be a better solution to the problem and is included in the default distro since 2.4.5

Answer (score 149):

Within **httpd.conf**, declare your variable(s) with: `Define` (Preferably at the very first line)
**Syntax**: `Define` `variable-name`  `variable-value`

**In this manner:**

```
#The line below creates the variable [static_path]
Define static_path C:/codebase/snp_static
```

**You can later use this variable like so:**

```
ServerRoot = ${static_path}
...
DocumentRoot = ${static_path}
...
<Directory ${static_path}>
...etc.
```

**You can even combine multiple variables:**

```
#Below, I am going to combine variables [server_space] and [static_path]
Define server_space c:/
Define static_path codebase/snp_static
...
ServerRoot = ${server_space}${static_path}
...
DocumentRoot = ${server_space}${static_path}
...
<Directory ${server_space}${static_path}>
...etc.
```

**Documentation**: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#define

Comment: mod_define not included in Apache 2.2 by default

Comment: Old original (made compatible with 2.0 and 2.2) mod_define is at http://people.apache.org/~rjung/mod_define/mod_define.html

Comment: This is definitely the ideal way to define variables in httpd conf files. I do hope the apachectl people stumble across this question.

Comment: Where can i find mod_define for windows lib apache 2.2 ?

Comment: @Radon8472 I may be mistaken, but I believe you can use the [define] "command" (or whatever the proper name may be) without `mod_define` on 2.2. After all, the documentation provided also works on 2.4 (and upwards). But just in case I am really, really wrong: https://people.apache.org/~rjung/mod_define/mod_define.html Have you tried it without modifications on your server?

Comment: I tried it on Apache 2.2 and like craigrs84 said, this module and the 'define' command is not part of Apache 2.2.
And I know the page where I can get the source of this module, what I liked to know, if I can get a precompiled version of this module for windows apache.

Comment: @radon8472 Have you tried creating a new question and linking this post to it? Because for what you are telling me, it sounds that your question worthy of having its own post

Comment: @Omar I think creating a question like this would only result in lots of "Compile the sourcecode yourself"-answers. I hoped, that someone has a downloadlink to precompiled files.

Comment: What if the `static_path` should contain a space? I keep getting syntax error, I tried sorrounding the string in quotes, double quotes and square brackets but none of them seems to be ok. I've searched the docs for this but there's no mention apparently...

Comment: The documentation that you linked to currently only mentions the "Define variable-name" syntax to declare the existence of a variable, but not the "Define variable-name variable-value" syntax for setting variables with arbitrary values. So it feels like using an undocumented feature to me.

Comment: @Cito My short answer: It WORKS

Comment: @Cito If you read the documentation carefully, it DOES explains BOTH. How to define a `variable-name` AND ALSO how to define a `variable-value`. It is right-smacked in the **main section** of the documentation, enclosed in a box to make it even more obvious to find: `Syntax: Define parameter-name [parameter-value]` JUST under the title: **Define Directive**

Comment: @Mark What OS? Windows? There's a way to get a non-spaced paths in windows. That technique will save your neck and is a quick workaround

Comment: @mark Read this too: https://medium.com/@leedowthwaite/dealing-with-spaces-in-paths-f26856aef06f

Let me know what OS and if this article helps

Comment: @Omar yes, Windows

Comment: @Mark try this https://superuser.com/questions/179449/windows-path-without-spaces-with-1 and the other stuff I suggested. Let me know what works (if it works)

Comment: @Omar You made me feel stupid, so I looked again. You're right, it DOES explain both, but only in the English version of the documentation. My browser shows the German version which currently does NOT explain both (what you see seems to be based on the preferred browser language). Maybe it was forgotten in the German version, or added later and the translation was not updated. As a side note, I think "it works" is in general not a very good argument when something works now, but when it is not documented and not part of the test suite, since it may then stop working in a future version.

Answer (score 10):

If all you want is simple variable substitution inside httpd.conf, then define an ordinary shell environment variable for the user that runs Apache, then use the ${ENVVAR} syntax to refer to it inside your httpd.conf file, see [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html)

Answer (score 5):

Apache2.4 I researched it out and here is what worked for me.
and tested using httpd_z.exe -t -D DUMP_RUN_CFG

```
   RESULTS:::
    ServerRoot: "C:/path/core/apache2"
    Main DocumentRoot: "C:/path/apache/htdocs"
    Main ErrorLog: "C:/path/core/apache2/logs/error.log"
    Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
    Mutex default: dir="C:/path/core/apache2/logs/" mechanism=default
    PidFile: "C:/path/core/apache2/logs/httpd.pid"
    Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
    Define: US_ROOTF=C:/path   **THIS IS THE ROOT PATH VARIABLE I JUST MADE**
    Define: php54


  #<IfDefine TEST>
    #  Define servername test.example.com
    #</IfDefine>
    #<IfDefine !TEST>
    #  Define servername www.example.com
    #  Define SSL
    #</IfDefine>
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/${servername}/htdocs
<IfDefine US_ROOTF>
 Define US_ROOTF C:/PATH   **The path i want the variable for**
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !US_ROOTF>
 Define US_ROOTF C:/PATH    **The path i want the variable for**
#  Define SSL
</IfDefine>
#DocumentRoot /var/www/${servername}/htdocs  OPTIONS ON HOW TO USE

EXAMPLE of use 
ServerRoot = ${US_ROOTF}
<IfDefine php54>
  LoadFile "${US_ROOTF}/core/php54/icudt53.dll"
PHPIniDir "${US_ROOTF}/core/php54/php_production.ini"
```

I was told never to use a direct HARD path to anything when serving something to the internet always use variables to help secure your system.

I found the hard way this is so true. Now I finally figured out how to set the variables for all services dealing with Apache i use them.

Hope it helps you too.

Comment: From the management perspective, it makes it all much easier to use variables to update and maintain a server when you need to removing old paths, rather than looking for these direct paths on each line of the http.conf (and any other places that apply) as well as security (when it applies)

Answer (score 4):

Late to the question but recently had this issue and fixed it like so:

`DEFINE path "C:\path/to the/directory"`

Then later use like so:

`DocumentRoot ${path}
<Directory ${path}>`

**Note:** In the path use \ after the drive letter

Answer (score 1):

If your apache project is not taking system's environmental variables which we added to bashrc, 
We can directly EXPORT variables to 
/etc/apache2/envvars file

example: export ADMIN='Bibin'