# Concatenate two strings in apache config

Tags: string, apache, string-concatenation

In an apache config file how can i concatenate two strings?

For example:

```
"hello" + "world"
// "helloworld"
```

---

**Why?**

One might want to do this to handle large Headers such as a `Content-Security-Policy` below is an example of my CSP. You can see it is nicely formatted for maintainability but when being sent in the Headers it has unwanted whitespace.

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "\
;default-src\
    'self'\
;child-src\
    'self'\
;connect-src\
    'self'\
;font-src\
    'self'\
    https://*.gstatic.com\
;form-action\
    'self';\
;frame-ancestors\
    'self'\
;frame-src\
    'self'\
;img-src\
    'self'\
    https://www.google.com/s2/favicons\
    https://www.google-analytics.com\
    https://*.gstatic.com\
    https://*.googleapis.com\
;object-src\
    'none'\
;script-src\
    'self'\
    'unsafe-eval'\
    https://www.google-analytics.com\
    https://*.googleapis.com\
;style-src\
    'self'\
    'unsafe-inline'\
    https://*.googleapis.com\
;\
"
```

Comment: Do you mean for a specific directive?

Comment: @madebydavid its more of a syntax question, but im my case im setting a very large header (CSP)

Comment: thanks for the syntax ;-) prefixing with `;` and the extra line-breaks +1

Answer (score 3):

I think you can declare variable like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15731921/6663198 
Then, you can easily concatenate your variables

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it doesn't really directly concatenate strings.
I've updated my question to give some context.

Answer (score 0):

```
OIDCScope "profile email openid offline_access"
OIDCRemoteUserClaim  sub

<Location "/app2">
    AuthType openid-connect
    Require valid-user
    ProxyPass   "http://192.168.10.237/myapp"
    ProxyPassReverse  "http://192.168.10.237/myapp"

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=PROXY_USER:%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER}] 
    RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER  %{PROXY_USER}e
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks and welcome to SO, could you care to elaborate on how this answers the question?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is to use either [setenv](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) or [define](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#define) directives to declare and define values and then simply refer it using `${VAR}` syntax as noted [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html#syntax).

In principle, the below should work.

```
$httpd -DTestCaseOne
```

> ...

```
<IfDefine TestCaseOne>
  Define dir_name_one media
  Define dir_name_two images
</IfDefine>
```

> ...

```
Include "/etc/httpd/sites/${dir_name_one}-${dir_name_two}/env.conf"
```

The server version for above references is - Apache 2.4

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
set $text = 'text';  
set $additional "${text}additional";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it doesn't really directly concatenate strings.
I've updated my question to give some context.

Answer (score 0):

So far the best I managed is to post-`edit*` the Header

Note the extra space   before the `\` new-line char

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "\
;default-src \
    'self' \
;child-src \
    'self' \
;connect-src \
    'self' \
"

# Remove unwanted whitespaces
Header edit* Content-Security-Policy "\s\s\s\s" ""
```

not 100% great, a bit expensive and could back-fire a bit, but well this is a way to do it