# Apache envvars issue

Tags: linux, apache, environment-variables, apache2, httpd.conf

I am trying to migrate from Apache 2.2 on Debian 7 to Apache 2.4 on CentOS 7.
There is a file named "envvars" on Debian 7 as below which has to exist on CentOS 7 as far as I know.

```
# envvars - default environment variables for apache2ctl

# this won't be correct after changing uid
unset HOME

# for supporting multiple apache2 instances
if [ "${APACHE_CONFDIR##/etc/apache2-}" != "${APACHE_CONFDIR}" ] ; then
    SUFFIX="-${APACHE_CONFDIR##/etc/apache2-}"
else
    SUFFIX=
fi

# Since there is no sane way to get the parsed apache2 config in scripts, some
# settings are defined via environment variables and then used in apache2ctl,
# /etc/init.d/apache2, /etc/logrotate.d/apache2, etc.
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
export APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX.pid
export APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX
export APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2$SUFFIX
# Only /var/log/apache2 is handled by /etc/logrotate.d/apache2.
export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2$SUFFIX
```

I created the same file under conf where httpd.conf located but it did not work and also add the contents to /etc/sysconfig/httpd but an error stops running the apache server as below.

```
Jun 17 17:48:35 ww-test httpd[5707]: [Wed Jun 17 17:48:35.473658 2020] [core:warn] [pid 5707] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
Jun 17 17:48:35 ww-test httpd[5707]: [Wed Jun 17 17:48:35.473857 2020] [core:warn] [pid 5707] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
Jun 17 17:48:35 ww-test httpd[5707]: [Wed Jun 17 17:48:35.473864 2020] [core:warn] [pid 5707] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
Jun 17 17:48:35 ww-test httpd[5707]: [Wed Jun 17 17:48:35.473885 2020] [core:warn] [pid 5707] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
Jun 17 17:48:35 ww-test httpd[5707]: [Wed Jun 17 17:48:35.495541 2020] [core:warn] [pid 5707] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
Jun 17 17:48:35 ww-test httpd[5707]: AH00543: httpd: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Jun 17 17:48:35 ww-test systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 17 17:48:35 ww-test systemd[1]: Ignoring invalid environment assignment 'export APACHE_RUN_USER=apache': /etc/sysconfig/httpd
Jun 17 17:48:35 ww-test systemd[1]: Ignoring invalid environment assignment 'export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=apache': /etc/sysconfig/httpd
Jun 17 17:48:35 ww-test systemd[1]: Ignoring invalid environment assignment 'export APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/httpd$SUFFIX.pid': /etc/sysconfig/httpd
Jun 17 17:48:35 ww-test systemd[1]: Ignoring invalid environment assignment 'export APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/httpd$SUFFIX': /etc/sysconfig/httpd
Jun 17 17:48:35 ww-test systemd[1]: Ignoring invalid environment assignment 'export APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/httpd$SUFFIX': /etc/sysconfig/httpd
Jun 17 17:48:35 ww-test systemd[1]: Ignoring invalid environment assignment 'export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/httpd$SUFFIX': /etc/sysconfig/httpd
Jun 17 17:48:35 ww-test kill[5708]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jun 17 17:48:35 ww-test systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 17 17:48:35 ww-test systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I tried source envvars to test if the environemts work but it did not.
Is there any way that I can add the environment variables so that it applies to whenever I start Apache?

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Within `httpd.conf`, declare your variable(s) with: Define (Preferably at the very first line)

```
Define APACHE_RUN_USER Apache
```

You can later use this variable like so:

```
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
```

Refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569080/how-to-define-a-variable-in-apaches-httpd-conf-file/15731921#15731921) for more information.